# Finding an exponential-like function given its values and graph to predict next values

Tags: exponential-function

I have table with 500 rows where I have a row number and cost value. Here is first 100 of them.

```
0,25
0,30
0,35
0,40
0,45
0,50
0,55
0,60
0,65
0,70
0,75
0,75
0,80
0,85
0,90
0,95
0,95
1,00
1,05
1,10
1,15
1,20
1,25
1,35
1,40
1,50
1,55
1,60
1,70
1,75
1,85
1,90
2,00
2,05
2,15
2,25
2,30
2,40
2,50
2,60
2,70
2,80
2,90
3,00
3,10
3,25
3,35
3,45
3,55
3,65
3,80
3,90
4,05
4,20
4,35
4,50
4,60
4,75
4,90
5,05
5,20
5,35
5,50
5,65
5,80
6,00
6,15
6,30
6,50
6,65
6,85
7,05
7,25
7,45
7,65
7,85
8,05
8,25
8,45
8,65
8,85
9,10
9,35
9,60
9,85
10,10
10,35
10,60
10,85
11,10
11,35
11,60
11,90
12,20
12,50
12,80
13,10
13,40
13,70
14,00
```

When I graph them, it looks exponential.

[image]

But when I look at difference between each row value, graph looks jittery.

[image]

Log of value

[image]

Factor (division) of value

[image]

What steps should be made if I wan't to create formula so that I can predict next 1000 (or more) values?

EDIT: Manually, I have got so far to use `0,178*SQRT(x)-0,730` to predict values, but it has an error in range of 0..25% with strange pattern.

[image]

It seems that there is something more to it than this simple formula.

How and what best fit curve software to use to get as close as possible?

PS: These are cost of stat points in RPG game. It could be that there is custom function with some sort of balancing. How to determine if it is custom?

Comment: The graph is expected to look jittery because your values are not continuous and because of noise. A more usual visual tool to see if your data is actually exponential is to make *logarithmic plot*: Basically, take the logarithm to your data and plot that - if it is exponential, it will be a straight line. Also, perhaps you wanted to plot the *factor* (and not difference)? That should be constant if it is exponential. If you want a function for your data, you should either *fit* an exponential function to your data or, perhaps more reliable, fit a straight line to the logarithm of the data.

Comment: @Lovsovs do you mean that I need to calculate (in Excel) `=LOG(B2; 10)` where B column are values and 10 is base, correct? And by factor you mean `=B3*B2` where B2 is previous value and B3 is next value, correct?

Comment: Correct and not correct: For the latter I mean the ratio of two consecutive datapoints (if all points have an equal distance on the $x$-axis), i.e. $k_n=\frac{B_n}{B_{n+1}}$ (or the other way around - it doesn't matter as long as you are consistent). If $k_n$ is the same number for all $n$, the data is exponential.

Comment: @Lovsovs Look at my edits. I hope I did it correctly.

Comment: Hmm, it clearly isn't exponential. As the resulting function (in the logplot) looks a *bit* like like a square root (like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.16sqrt(x)-0.5+for+x%3D0..500)), the function you're looking for might be on the form $ae^{b\sqrt{x}}$ but perhaps it just isn't a simple function.

Comment: @Lovsovs Yeah, it really looks like square root! How did you came up with those coefficients in `0,16 * sqrt(A1) - 0,5`? Can you please explain in full length answer, what steps should be made to come up with your assumptions, and what should be done next, to determine if it is or it is not exponent and how to get to the result?

Comment: Those coefficients were just a (probably bad) guess. I will make an answer to collect all the information.

Comment: @Lovsovs By playing with those two numbers, I came up to closer line using `0,177 * sqrt(A1) - 0,73` see plot https://image.ibb.co/izgjTv/Snap_2017_03_17_at_14_22_04.jpg But still, middle does not match and it seems, that with higher values it is incrementing too fast.

Comment: You need to use some software built for fitting (look up how to do it with excel) to get the best results. I tried to construct an answer, but I wasn't able to construct a model I think I would fit better than the square root, so I'm holding off on that for now. I might answer later if I figure it out, but don't count on it. Good luck!

Comment: @Lovsovs Please make an answer and collect all the information like you promised :) What to do now with that log plot? How to get to the formula to calculate value predictions?

Answer (score 2):

As seen from the logplot, your function $f(x)$ is *not* exponential (the line is not straight). However, observe that it looks a bit like a square root, so

$$f(x)=ae^{b\sqrt{x}}$$
would be a potential model to fit after. But note how your function actually is zero (for $x=1$ it seems). An exponential function can't do this ($e^0=1$). This hints that the function may instead be of the form 
$$f(x)=axe^{b\sqrt{x}},$$
which would be my best guess (it has [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20ln(xe%5E(sqrt(x))) form - ignore the orange lines). To find the coefficients $a,b$ that fits your data the best, you need to usage some dedicated software (Excel might be able to fit after custom functions, I don't know) to find the best guess.

Good luck!

Comment: How to put in excel that last formula? I tried with `=$I$2 * $A3 * EXP($I$3 * SQRT($A3))` where `$A3` is x, `$I$2` is a, `$I$3` is b. But whatever I do with coefficients it does not come close to values.

Comment: @Deele The values need to be very small, around $a=1.1$ and $b=-0.1$. However, you shouldn't do this "by hand", you should get some software to do it for you, as I've been trying to tell you.

Comment: @Deele Install the built-in, but optional, Solver Add-on for Excel. It can minimize the error by tweaking the parameters.